# ruby query with function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, math

```
# search for a particular date (between two other dates)    
  a = self.where('created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', yes, tom)
# search for a particular location
  a = a.each do |loc|
    if coorDist(loc.lat, loc.lng, lat, lng) < dist
      return loc
    end
  end
```

I'm trying to return a hash like the initial value of `a` here.  How do I loop through the hash and collect the entities that meet the condition of this `if` statement??  The way it is there, it just returns the first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.select! do |loc|
  coorDist(loc.lat, loc.lng, lat, long) < dist
end
```

If you are just returning the hash, use `select` instead of `select!`.

Comment: had to use the .select { |loc| etc }.  each uses the do.  you got it though, thank you!  i feel like that was easy, and should probably go to bed...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [`#each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html#method-i-each) and `if`, use [`#select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select).

```
# search for a particular location
a = a.select do |loc|
  coorDist(loc.lat, loc.lng, lat, lng) < dist
end
```